# Regex For Work Items in Team Services API

Tags: regex, azure-devops, tfs-workitem, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm retrieving a list of Work Items using the VSTS API and would like to display them on my web app. I can successfully return a list of the work items in the format below:

{"count":1,"value":[{"id":246,"rev":4,"fields":{"System.Id":246,"System.State":"New","System.Title":"test1"},"url":"https://example.visualstudio.com/_apis/wit/workItems/246"}]}

I have tried a regular expression to get the values from this HTTP response with the following code:

```
HttpResponseMessage getWorkItemsHttpResponse = client.GetAsync("_apis/wit/workitems?ids=" + ids + "&fields=System.Id,System.Title,System.State&asOf=" + workItemQueryResult.asOf + "&api-version=2.2").Result;

                    if (getWorkItemsHttpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        result = getWorkItemsHttpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                        // Regular expression to extract work item values to display    
                        string parseWI = result.ToString();
                        var match = Regex.Match(parseWI, "\"System.ID\": (.*)");
                        workItemsToDisplay = (match.Groups[1].Value);


                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return workItemsToDisplay;

    }
```

This is refusing to return anything though and leaves the textbox I display the workItemsToDisplay in empty. I'm not familiar with regular expressions and i'm sure this is where the issue stems from. Not sure if Microsoft already has sample code to construct a display of Work Items from the response.

Comment: That's JSON. Use a JSON parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a regex. That's JSON, use a JSON parsing library ([JSON.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) is the de facto standard in the .NET world) and then you can easily retrieve specific fields.

Comment: Having issues creating the corresponding classes for the JSON string. For example, I can't declare System.ID property since it has the '.' character.

Comment: There should be plenty of Googleable resources showing you how to use JSON .NET. The answer to the question "How do I use a regex to parse JSON?" is "Don't, use a JSON parsing tool."